# THREE.JS postprocessing blur render regions

Tags: three.js, blur, regions, post-processing

I need to blur render but not whole, only fragments. Frozen "glass" shapes will flowed over (SVG animated transparent shapes over WebGl animation). The problem is local frozen effect. Whether is some effect composer or context.readPixels + FastBlur.js makes sense or maybe css + masks ? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

I did it:
WebGl shader blur (Three.js render passes) + mask texture (image = additional invisible canvas element where shapes are drawn). SVG is an independent element, but gives information about kind of shapes and positions for mask texture and displays shapes of course. A bit crazy but works and very fast.